# Form_URN and Current Item URL - both do not work when used in a Task email notification to provide a clickable link

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I found in a few threads that I could use Form_URN in my email notifications that a task was over due, but this does not work for me.

I have tried in several different workflows, so I know it isn't specific to just one. I have a secondary workflow that sets due dates and also emails the user if the due date is in the past.

I used the Form URN as you can see from the pic. Any advice?

[image: form_urn pic]

I also tried using Workflow Context: Current Item URL and look at this odd behavior, the link is DUPLICATED as you can see in the flyout.

[image]

Comment: i tried also using Workflow Context: Current Item URL and that doesn't work either...it returns DOUBLE url.

Comment: It returns Double the URL because that is the format of the inofpath URL field.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Current Task:Form_URN` to get a link to the currently assigned task.

Comment: Hint: Form_URN will only work inside a Task's actions, when the task has already been created. In other words it won't work "Before the task has been assigned" which I was doing :|